# New Safari 14.0 Intelligent Tracking Prevention vs DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials

Tags: safari, privacy, safari-extensions

I've recently updated Safari to version 14.0 and now there's a new Intelligent Tracking Prevention panel showing blocked trackers.

I've been using DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials extension for blocking trackers for 2 years now, and I'm now ondering if it is still useful after this safari update?

In the Safari panel there's this message:

```
Known trackers are independently identified by DuckDuckGo.
```

So they probably works the same. Can I remove DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials extension, or I will lose something doing so?

Comment: [It seems](https://thenextweb.com/security/2020/03/06/duckduckgo-wants-devs-to-use-its-list-of-web-trackers-to-protect-your-privacy-online/) that DuckDuckGo encourages other browsers to do the same as Safari, so I think we can assume they think it is at least as good as their extension.